# Как изменить цвет Scrollbar со стандартного на собственные цвета?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, style, scrollbar

Сейчас цвет стандартный, как его изменить, например, на красный?

```py
        ...
        self.hor_scrollbar = Scrollbar(self.hor_scroll_frame_)
        self.hor_scrollbar.configure(borderwidth=0)
        self.hor_scrollbar.config(command=self.hor_scroll_frame.xview, orient=HORIZONTAL)
        self.hor_scrollbar.pack(side=BOTTOM, fill=X)
        self.hor_scroll_frame.configure(xscrollcommand=self.hor_scrollbar.set)
        ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
import tkinter as tk                 
from tkinter import ttk


class Gui:
    def __init__(self, mainframe):

        style = ttk.Style()
        style.theme_use('clam')

        style.configure(
            "Horizontal.TScrollbar", 
            gripcount=0,
            background="Green", 
            darkcolor="DarkGreen", 
            lightcolor="LightGreen",
            troughcolor="red", 
            bordercolor="blue", 
            arrowcolor="white"
        )

        self.mainframe = mainframe
        self.mainframe.title("Title")

        scrl_attr_frame = ttk.Frame(self.mainframe)                            
        scrl_attr_frame.grid(column=0, row=5, sticky="ns")                                           
        scrl_attr_frame.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)                                                   
        attr_canvas = tk.Canvas(scrl_attr_frame)
        
        h_scroll = ttk.Scrollbar(
            scrl_attr_frame,
            orient="horizontal", 
            command=attr_canvas.xview
        )

        attr_canvas.configure(xscrollcommand=h_scroll.set)                                       
        attr_canvas.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky="ns")                                                                            
        h_scroll.grid(column=0, row=1, sticky="we") 

        attr_frame = ttk.Frame(attr_canvas)                                                        
        attr_frame.grid(column=0,row=0, sticky="ns")                                                 
        attr_canvas.create_window((0, 0), window=attr_frame, anchor='nw')
        attr_frame.bind(
            "<Configure>", 
            lambda event, canvas=attr_canvas: 
            canvas.configure(
                scrollregion=canvas.bbox("all"),
                width=200,
                height=200,
                takefocus=False,
                highlightthickness=0
            )
        )

        tree_columns = ("A", "B", "C")
        self.tree = ttk.Treeview(
            attr_frame,
            columns=tree_columns, 
            show="headings",
            takefocus=False
        )
        self.tree.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky='nsew')

        for head in tree_columns:
            self.tree.heading(head, text=head,anchor="w")


root = tk.Tk()
myapp = Gui(root)
root.mainloop()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]